# Is there a way to get GPS location on a time interval instead of when the position changes?

Tags: android, gps

My client wants a GPS app that will produce a spreadsheet of all the GPS locations in equal time intervals.  You can set the time interval using a spinner.

Right now my app gets the new GPS location when the location changes using `LocationManager` manager's `onLocationChanged(Location loc)` callback.

Is there a way to get the new GPS locations on time intervals instead of when the position changes?

Code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
  setContentView(R.layout.main);  


  //if you want to lock screen for always Portrait mode    
  setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo  
  .SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);  

  pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);  
  pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);  

  viewLog= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ViewLong); 
  viewLat= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ViewLat); 

  locationMangaer = (LocationManager)   
  getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);  
  StartGPS();
 }  


void  StartGPS()
{

 flag = displayGpsStatus();  
  if (flag) {  


   pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  
   locationListener = new MyLocationListener();  

   locationMangaer.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager .GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 10,locationListener);  

   } else {  
   alertbox("Gps Status!!", "Your GPS is: OFF");  
  }  

 }  




@Override  
 public void onClick(View v) {  

 }  



 /*----------Listener class to get coordinates ------------- */  
 private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {  
        @Override  
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {  

            String longitude = "Longitude: " +loc.getLongitude(); 
               viewLog.setText(longitude);  
               String latitude = "Latitude: " +loc.getLatitude(); 
               viewLat.setText( latitude); 
               pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); 

        }  

        @Override  
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {  
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub           
        }  

        @Override  
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {  
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub           
        }  

        @Override  
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider,   
  int status, Bundle extras) {  
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub           
        }  
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Register for location updates as you are now. Ignore the values passed to your `LocationListener`. On your desired polling frequency, call `getLastKnownLocation()` for whatever provider you are using for your location updates.